# How to convert from one date time format to another in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe where the date times can be either in the format `Wed Oct 02 10:55:08 BST 2019` or
`Wed Oct 02 10:55:08 GMT 2019`.

I want all the these date times to be in datetimes in the format of `2019-01-10 10:55:08` where the times are GMT.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to shift the BST dates to be an hour earlier as well? Or just ignore the time zone?

Comment: I want to shift them an hour earlier

Comment: Have you had a look at [`tz_convert`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.tz_convert.html)? Also you might want to consider making a new indicator column to record if the time was originally BST or GMT.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use from datetime of the standard library and convert to date time

```
from datetime import datetime



df['datecolumn'].apply(lambda x: 
   datetime.strptime(x, "%a %b %d %I:%M:%S GMT %Y") if 'GMT' in x else x)
```